# using android facebook sdk without oauth login, only SSO

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

Is it possible to use the android facebook sdk auth, but only for SS0 and disable the fallback to oauth.  Another words,  only allow the user who has the facebook app installed and is the registered user for the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is internally using OAuth - so I don't think this its possible...

Comment: Absolutely...the end-point is implemented in Oauth....so, basically u can do nothing about it